# How does Hadoop actually accept MR jobs and input data?

Tags: java, hadoop

All of the introductory tutorials and docs that I can find on Hadoop have simple/contrived (word count-style) examples, where each of them is submitted to MR by:

1. SSHing into the JobTracker node
2. Making sure that a JAR file containing the MR job is on HDFS
3. Running an HDFS command of the form `bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/my-map-reduce.jar <someArgs>` that actually runs Hadoop/MR
4. Either reading the MR result from the command-line or opening a text file containing the result

Although these examples are great for showing total newbies how to work with Hadoop, it doesn't show me how Java code actually integrates with Hadoop/MR at the API level. I *guess* I am sort of expecting that:

1. Hadoop exposes some kind of client access/API for submitting MR jobs to the cluster
2. Once the jobs are complete, some asynchronous mechanism (callback, listener, etc.) reports the result back to the client

So, something *like* this (Groovy pseudo-code):

```
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver().run(args)
    }

    void run(String[] args) {
        MapReduceJob myBigDataComputation = new SolveTheMeaningOfLifeJob(convertToHadoopInputs(args), new MapReduceCallback() {
            @Override
            void onResult() {
                // Now that you know the meaning of life, do nothing.
            }
        })

        HadoopClusterClient hadoopClient = new HadoopClusterClient("http://my-hadoop.example.com/jobtracker")
        hadoopClient.submit(myBigDataComputation)
    }
}
```

So I ask: Surely the simple examples in all the introductory tutorials, where you SSH into nodes and run Hadoop from the CLI, and open text files to view its results...surely that can't be the way Big Data companies *actually* integrate with Hadoop. Surely, *something* along the lines of my pseudo-code snippet above is used to kick off an MR job and fetch its results.  **What is it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one word, kicking off an MR job can be done, using Oozie scheduler. But before that, you write a map reduce job. It has the driver class which is the starting point of the job. You give all information needed for the job to run in Driver class: like map input, mapper class, if any partitioners, config details and reducer details.

Once these are there in jar file, and you start a job as above(hadoop jar) using CLI(in reality oozie does it), the rest is taken care by Hadoop ecosystem. Hope I answered your question

Comment: Thanks @Ramzy (+1) but can this really be true?!? You're telling me the *only* way to run Hadoop is either by: (1) kicking it off manually from the command line, or (2) scheduling MR jobs to run?!? You're saying there's no way to actually run it on-the-fly, on-demand?!? Say it isn't so!

Comment: "on-the-fly" - This word is important. Hadoop is designed for batch process on large scale. So that itself says it. And I dont think, "running Hadoop" phrase is correct. because its the eco system that performs the job. if you r frm a a web application background, I understand "on the fly" thing. Its a different world here. There is data  & analysis. Some one's got to start the job which does analysis on data.Ther's another meaning for "on the fly" phrase in Real time streaming world. Eventually there are different set of technologies to handle that requirement like Storm, Spark and others.